# CakePHP capitalizes plugin name in URLs generated by paginate

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I have a plugin called "Admin". When I go to `/admin/users` and view the list of users the links generated by paginate all look like `/Admin/users/index/page:2`.

If I visit `/admin/users/index/page:2` (note the lower case "a") the links generated by paginate are correct again.

Any idea on how to fix this?

#### edit:

I'm not sure why this was down-voted.

I updated the URLs above

```
// Plugin/Admin/Config/routes.php
Router::Connect('/admin/:controller', array('plugin' => 'Admin', 'controller' => ':controller'));
Router::Connect('/admin/:controller/:action', array('plugin' => 'Admin', 'controller' => ':controller', 'action' => ':action'));
```

Removing those two lines seemed to fix my issue.

Comment: Do you have a controller and a plugin both named admin? It looks like it's trying to follow it's own naming conventions and assuming admin is a controller and capitalizing it

Comment: "/Admin/index/page:2" => you meant `/admin/users/index/page:2` right?

Comment: You need to add the contents of your routes file to the question to be able to answer

Comment: Thanks for the hint on where to look for my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting out these lines or changing the "A" in admin to "a" fixed it.  Thanks @AD7six

```
// Plugin/Admin/Config/routes.php
Router::Connect('/admin/:controller', array('plugin' => 'admin', 'controller' => ':controller'));
Router::Connect('/admin/:controller/:action', array('plugin' => 'admin', 'controller' => ':controller', 'action' => ':action'));
```

Comment: also, it is `Router::connect()` - methods start lowercase (even though it should work both ways).